# SQL Procedure of Procedures Execution Schedule

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-execution-plan

If I create a procedure in SQL Server 2012 with (stock settings) that is primarily constructed of procedures as:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[zpr_proc_of_proc]
AS

     EXEC zpr_proc1

     EXEC zpr_proc2

     EXEC zpr_proc3

     EXEC zpr_proc4

     SELECT * FROM table

END PROCEDURE:
```

Will the execution wait for the completion of the previous procedure, ie. complete execution of zpr_proc1 before moving to zpr_proc2, or will it simply `EXEC`, and move to the next `EXEC` thus possibly allowing overlap in the execution of the procedures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execution(EXEC) in SQL is synchronous so the execution of zpr_proc1 will be completed before moving to zpr_proc2 and so on.